# How to set environment variables from within powershell?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, dotnet, powershell

How do I make `foo` an environment variable [accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59868975/262852) through `printenv` on bash?

```
PS /home/thufir/powershell/helloPSTwitterAPI> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell/helloPSTwitterAPI> $env:foo = 'x' * 333 + '!'      
PS /home/thufir/powershell/helloPSTwitterAPI> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell/helloPSTwitterAPI> $env:foo
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx!
PS /home/thufir/powershell/helloPSTwitterAPI>
```

I would like to use powershell to set an environment variable rather than using `setenv` itself so that Visual Studio Code, and bash, will [pick up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59882280/262852) the variables when running powershell scripts.

Comment: PowerShell may be case sensitive, as is implied in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7 . What happens when you use Env instead of env ?

Comment: Nope.  I'm fairly sure it's doable, just don't know how.  Thanks, though, @K7AAY

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as described below:

> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('DOCKER_HOST','docker.artofshell.com')

[See also](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/25/powershell-environment-variables/)

This way the environment variable (in this case `DOCKER_HOST`) is created permanently as if you would've created it via the windows control panel.